# how to trace gmail sender from header?

Tags: email, header, gmail

Everyone knows changing mail address in address bar and pretending to send mail from someone else's accout is easy..
so i looked up on google "find out where email came from"
some of the links suggest-- 1. Log into your account and open the email in question.

1. Click on the down arrow that’s to the right of the Reply link. Choose Show Original from the list.
2. Now here’s the technical part that I was telling you about earlier! You need to look for the lines of text that start with “Received: from“.

I did all above steps but found out that gmail uses mail client ip as sender ip and not the ip of that particular PC(For security purpose they say...) It has sender's IP as mr. google.com and some private netwk IP(10.43.103.195)

so now my problem is -- is there any damn way in the world to trace where the hell did this mail come from??!!(at least IP of sender)?

This is the header i got when i followed above 3 steps which is of no use...--

```
Delivered-To: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.204.40.79 with SMTP id j15csp110512bke;
        Fri, 22 Mar 2013 01:55:20 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com designates 10.43.103.195 as permitted sender) client-ip=10.43.103.195
Authentication-Results: mr.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com designates 10.43.103.195 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com
X-Received: from mr.google.com ([10.43.103.195])
        by 10.43.103.195 with SMTP id dj3mr548753icc.3.1363942518977 (num_hops = 1);
        Fri, 22 Mar 2013 01:55:18 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=x-received:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to
         :content-type;
        bh=Vi/MI39WKoec07maKoVjz5/ZzUxhO1k+BoeRUkBbWOc=;
        b=kZ/EniFvV15mZ9iBeKNiKsJsQvWHL5N8zqrazVxeKmAARQLotyAAIDU7Or9Xc1OBwY
         cwuPqSKmVX1RV7tX5wwcdYyzEA/gmskzgGteimv0BInTzVO7dwgi4gU5cZYdm6Qj/GMo
         rJfGs5ty6VjidYMFwyn0K5Z0frh2NX2e7RXP0R6da6U5WMU2bQ9epOD4ZhKF+bSdUvb9
         WGu3/HWJNTgwrFivspsA6q0M6JkQWYFM6J83h62kIgU897gsXkRlwPacn63tHySC6CNm
         DJZGzRJryQZEJTI4owOImP6XDrK+uxPDFAiTnIG5xFR8PBXsQp+FP+XcsqIHqXSjCtl1
         xXdQ==
X-Received: by 10.43.103.195 with SMTP id dj3mr548753icc.3.1363942518971; Fri,
 22 Mar 2013 01:55:18 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.64.134.164 with HTTP; Fri, 22 Mar 2013 01:54:58 -0700 (PDT)
From: xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Date: Fri, 22 Mar 2013 14:24:58 +0530
Message-ID: <CACD4ahHmkbNCj9G5taUkXYC=K=n4qVvxY75SSSv3hUG00r6dkQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: 
To: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec5171a235666e504d87f9dd8

--bcaec5171a235666e504d87f9dd8
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sender uses gmail/yahoo/hotmail etc. to send an email (ie. if they don't use a third-party software like Outlook or Thunderbird), there is no way to find out the "PC IP address" because it's hidden for 'privacy reasons.' Probably the only legitimate way (other than through legal means) is to ask the sender to reveal their IP address (using such tools like https://verifyyourip.com).